# Error in launching java application - eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting an error while launching even a simple application in eclipse.

"An internal error occurred during: "Launching Test".
null argument:"

Any solution for the error ?

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: You should check the log at "workspace/.metadata/.log". Are you using Maven? Try to activate the JPA Configurator.

Comment: Reinstall the eclipse should help

Comment: getting "!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 4 2018-10-23 17:10:20.617
!MESSAGE Could not determine Java version for location C:\Tools\Java\JRE7-64." on eclipse startup...

Comment: Another error message :- !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 4 2018-10-23 17:10:57.858
!MESSAGE Failed to retrieve default libraries for C:\Tools\Java\JRE7-64

Comment: @NinadSinghNegi Check whether your JAVA_HOME environment variable is set properly. Also check Project properties(Java Compiler, Facets) are configured properly. Ref. [Eclipse Forum Issue](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/76915/)

Comment: Checked that. Everything seems to be correct. Getting the below error on launching application.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.launching 4 4 2018-10-23 19:34:09.733
!MESSAGE Could not determine Java version for location C:\Tools\Java\JDK8-64.

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2018-10-23 19:34:09.734
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Launching Test".
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:88)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Assert.isNotNull(Assert.java:76)

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? What is configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_? Does choosing here a JDK as default JRE fix your issue? What result do you get for `C:\Tools\Java\JRE7-64\bin\java -version` on the command line?

Comment: @howlger, I'm using eclipse 2018-09 (4.9.0). In 'Installed JREs', I've set the path to the JRE 8 home (I've tried the same with multiple JREs). The o/p of the command displays the respective java version i.e. 1.7.0_79 in this case.

Comment: Can you please describe step by step what you have done and confirm the result with screenshots? Please edit your question instead of posting fragments in comments. The error message (_"Launching Test"_) doesn't match what you're supposed to have done (_"launching java application"_).